# Cannot install the app while installing an archive build

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

currently I'm working on a flutter project and I'm new to it. The app is working fine on android device and iOS simulator. But when I try to run the app on iOS real device I'm getting issues. I tried in two ways,

1. I took a direct run build to a real device, and that time it is working and app is installed on my phone. But when I open the same app after disconnecting the connection between phone and Xcode, or when open after killing the direct run, it is simply opening the app and immediately closing. And showing no errors.
2. And I took an archive build, using diawi.com I convert .ipa file into a link, and when I try to install the app, after showing the animation of downloading and installing the app turns to a disable look(app icon changed to grey color) and when I open the app it says, cannot install the app.
   I don't know why it is happening. I tried through Automatically and manually code signing style. But in both case I'm getting this issue. But when I run a simulator there is no issue. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Do you have an Apple developer account?

Comment: @Gokul, Yes I have. And I created the provision profile for developement and adhoc distribution.

Comment: Consider adding Crashlytics or Bugsnag to your app. That will help you get crash reports of the app when you're not connected to Xcode

Comment: @SylvanDAsh  ok Thanks